# Two 50% columns with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do create 2 columns of 50% with Twitter Bootstrap 3? What I've tried:

```
<div class="container">
<!-- Footer -->
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-info">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6"><h3>Contact Us</h3></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6"><h3>Products & Services</h3></div>
    </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>    
<!-- End Footer -->
```

Answer (score 9):

It's your answer:

Jsfiddle : **http://jsfiddle.net/g9y4P/**

always 50% width

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

First, layout the proper semantic for the grid

**Why it's not working in your case??**

- You have used `col-lg-6` (  <strike>[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ne2f7/3/)</strike>) which is for `Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)`, you have to gives the `class`es for smaller screen sizes too, thats what you missed!!( [**demo with only one column set to adapt to screens**](http://jsfiddle.net/ne2f7/4/) )
- Also, since you are following BS markup...its always a good practice to define the width of your container like `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">` which makes it adapt to various viewports!

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ne2f7/2/)

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Footer -->
        <div class="footer" style="border:1px solid #000">
            <div class="footer-info">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                         <h3>Products & Services</h3> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--- //container -->
</div>
<!--- //col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12-->
<!-- End Footer -->
```

Comment: I don't know why the downvote, but you answer answered fully to the question, I upvote, else it's not fair.

Comment: @Jahnux73 : hehe..thanks mate...so did you got a final answer...i dont see any accepted answer, you still looking for some explaination or clarification!!?? :)

Answer (score 4):

According to twitter bootstrap:

> Rows must be placed within a .container for proper alignment and padding.

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-info container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6"><h3>Contact Us</h3></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6"><h3>Products & Services</h3></div>
    </div>      
  </div>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro

Answer (score 1):

I cant see the problem´:

http://jsfiddle.net/AYd5t/

you can try using

`.col-md-6`  instead of `.col-xs-6`

you can check the documentation here:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: The difference in md vs xs is for responsive sites. if you still want to have 50% columns at the smallest size(xs) then you need to use xs not md.

Comment: I've disabled responsiveness on this site, would that be a problem.

Comment: I know! But project requirements.

Answer (score 1):

`col-xs-*` has been dropped in Bootstrap 4+ in favor of `col-*`

Please find the answer here: [`col-xs-*` not working in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794746/col-xs-not-working-in-bootstrap-4?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing an obvious issue with the snippet you posted. Can you post your full HTML? A JS Bin or JS Fiddle would be ideal.

If that doesn't work for you, perhaps check that you've an outer div with a class called "container", and that your links to the Bootstrap CSS and JS files are valid.