# `col-xs-*` not working in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, text-alignment

I have not encountered this before, and I am having a very hard time trying to find the solution. When having a column equal to medium in bootstrap like so:

```
<h1 class="text-center">Hello, world!</h1>

  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
              <h1>vicki williams</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

The text-align works fine:
[image]

But when making the column equal to extra small like so:

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
              <h1>vicki williams</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Then the text-align no longer works:
[image]

Is there some bootstrap concept that I am not understanding or is this in fact a error like I think it is. I have never had this issue, as my text always has aligned in the past with xs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="text-center">Hello, world!</h1>

      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                  <h1>vicki williams</h1>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `col-xs-*` no longer exists in the latest v4 release that's why you're seeing this. The `col-xs-12` doesn't have a width set of 100% like your `col-md-12`. Check DevTools to see everything and see this [Pull](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/20934)

Answer (score 591, accepted):

`col-xs-*` have been dropped in Bootstrap 4 in favor of `col-*`.

Replace `col-xs-12` with `col-12` and it will work as expected.

Also note `col-xs-offset-{n}` were replaced by `offset-{n}` in v4.

Comment: Always check [docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options). Happy coding! :: }<(((*> ::

Comment: This is not something you normally would check docs for.  I was all over the docs and missed this too.  I had thought, over two bs4 site migrations now, that col was for generic, and col-xs would be specific, however in hindsight this makes no sense, because being mobile first, xs and up is generic (default).  Thanks for the reminder, I think i did skim that during my last migration, but was stuck on this on this one.

Comment: Please read this answer about what changed [between v3 and v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091275/upgrading-bootstrap-from-3-3-4-to-4-0/49091398#49091398).) and also a link to a tool, should you decide to go that way. It's not an easy task and IMHO it's easier to work on clean template and just insert the php than change the markup.

Comment: This is not explained int the docs tao, thank you very much!

Comment: @tao- sir I tried col-sm-12 Also it's not working

Comment: @Kapil, in Bootstrap v4, `col-sm-12`, applies: `flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%` when the viewport (screen) has a width below `576px`. What do you mean by *"it's not working"*? What are you expecting? Consider asking a different question. This one is about `col-xs-*` classes not being included in v4. You likely have a different problem.

Comment: @tao: sir I have and card in which I used sm but it's not showing in full screen?

Comment: That means your problem has absolutely nothing to do with this question or with this answer. You can't ask new questions in comments. You have to ask it as a separate question. Make sure to create a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. And please read [ask].

Comment: It's remarkable how **Bootstrap** developers take so much effort to ensure compatibility between different versions is absolutely and completely broken.

Answer (score 30):

I just wondered, why `col-xs-6` did not work for me but then I found the answer in the Bootstrap 4 documentation. The class prefix for extra small devices is now **`col-`** while in the previous versions it was `col-xs`.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#grid-options

Bootstrap 4 dropped all `col-xs-*` classes, so use `col-*` instead. For example `col-xs-6` replaced by `col-6`.

Answer (score 16):

They dropped XS because Bootstrap is considered a mobile-first development tool. It's default is considered xs and so doesn't need to be defined.

Comment: They could have added it as an alternative instead of dropping it. It seems they certainly need to **guarantee broken compatibility between different versions**, and in that they have succeeded.

Answer (score 12):

In [Bootstrap 4.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/), col-xs-{value} is replaced by col-{value}

There is no change in *sm, md, lg, xl* remains the same.

.col-{value}
.col-sm-{value}
 
.col-md-{value}
 
.col-lg-{value}
 
.col-xl-{value}

Answer (score 2):

you could do this, if you want to use the old syntax (or don't want to rewrite every template)

```
@for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {
  @include media-breakpoint-up(xs) {
    .col-xs-#{$i} {
      @include make-col-ready();
      @include make-col($i);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to apply an extra small class in Bootstrap 4,you need to use col-*.
important thing to know is that col-xs-* is dropped in Bootstrap4

Comment: Please don't repeat old, existing, highly-ranked answers. That doesn't add value to the community.