# Upgrading Bootstrap from 3.3.4 to 4.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I used to have my website with `Boostrap 3.3.4`, and since I moved to `Bootstrap 4` everything is broken.

Essentially the structure of my website was very simple, a container that contained some `jumbotrons` and some `panels`

```
<body>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
            <div><img src="img/hello.jpg" style="width: 35%" class="img-responsive" title="Hello" alt="World"></div>
            <h2>my website!!</h2>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h4> stackoverflow </h4>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education" aria-hidden="true"></span><strong> This is reall cool! </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and so on.

CSS would be simply

```
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  background:white;
  padding: 30px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
}

.jumbotron {
  background: white;
}
```

Here I would have a suite of **centered**, **responsive** nice blocks (with roundede edges) that would NOT take the full width of the screen.

I have no idea how to adapt that with `Bootstrap 4`.

Comment: why the downvotes? this is an interesting question with a good answer

Comment: I'd also be interested on why people downvoted. From my point of view the intention to upgrade from v3 to v4 is normal, especially when one doesn't know much about Bootstrap. Therefore this question has the potential to be useful for future users.

Comment: I agree with that :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Please note this answer was provided 6 years ago. For obvious reasons, it is outdated. Some parts of it still apply for the `v4` > `v5` upgrade, though.

---

**Initial answer:**

Whenever you switch from one major version to another, with any software, you should expect breaking changes.

In the case of Bootstrap, it's more than *breaking-changes*. It's almost a completely new library (in fact, it is completely rewritten, for the most part!). In terms of development, think of it as a different library <strike>vaguely</strike> resembling the old one.

The best advice I could give you is to revert to v3. If you want to take advantage of the fully developed product, use latest v3 available.  There are very few real life cases where <strike>upgrading</strike> switching a functional website from Bootstrap v3 to Bootstrap v4 makes sense in terms of development time and/or investment.

If you are really determined to do this (maybe for educational purposes or whatnot), consider rebuilding it from scratch, using v4. If you do need to convert old templates (HTML markup) run them through the Bootstrap [**`v3 to v4 markup converter`**](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/).

But keep in mind that even with this tool or similar, considering all changes in terms of architecture, layout, JavaScript plugins, form elements, switch from glyphicons to font awesome, switch from LESS to SASS, renamed variables, changed responsive breakpoints and any custom CSS you (or any v3 theme/plugin/add-on) might currently use for overriding defaults, you still have a lot of chances of messing it up and you're better off (and with a superior end product) if you rebuild from scratch, IMHO.

Moving from v3 to v4 makes a lot more sense in terms of: *"I used to develop websites using v3 and now I use v4 in new projects"*, rather than *"I upgraded a website from v3 to v4"*.
<strike>v3 is **not obsolete and will not be for a good number of years**.

In fact, it is a much more more suitable option for a production environment than v4 at the moment. In this regard, a quick look at [bootstrap-4](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4) questions, will confirm it's not (yet) production ready. Basic functionality is still broken or at least under-developed on widely used devices.</strike>

---

In the particular case of your markup, this should do:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around  align-items-center">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=2bb144720a66" style="width: 35%" class="img-fluid" title="Hello" alt="World">
    </div>
    <h2>my website!!</h2>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4> stack<b>overflow</b> </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4><i class="fa fa-university"></i><strong> This is reall cool! </strong></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Note I replaced `glyphicon` with `fa` as Bootstrap v4 uses font awesome icons and I also centered the logo as a reminder v4 makes use of flexbox to center and evenly distribute, should you ever need it (i.e.: place `<h2>` inside `.d-flex` to align and distribute in line with logo)

Comment: That's really something and as you said in a comment somewhere else, that it rarely makes sense to go from v3 to v4 and for what the site is and looks like and works well, I'll be sticking with v3. That was very well-written I might add Andrei and quite informative.

Comment: @Funk, I might just add v4 is now production ready. It still suffers from lack of plugins, but it's getting a lot of traction, as most modern frameworks (React, Angular) integrated it and cool themes are already up for grabbing. A new project? Go v4. Switch a dinosaur from v3 to it? Meh...

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Aye, for sure I'll use v4 on any new project. Oh, and I love dinosaurs. Least I know what to expect from them, *heh!*; quite the ride!

Comment: "v3 is not obsolete and will not be for a good number of years."  - well that didn't age well! :)   Bootstrap v3 was made obsolete in July 2019 and should no longer be used.

Comment: @Nick, I'd still think twice about upgrading to v4 a fully working website made on Bootstrap v3. It's not like it stopped working in 2019 and one could argue it's a well rounded product. They just stopped developing it. I've striked that statement out, nonetheless. It no longer holds true.

Comment: It's more than it contains security vulnerabilities and therefore can't be used on live websites.