# Bootstrap 4 - margin 0 does not work

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I noticed that `margin: 0px` has no effect. If you look on the screenshot, then you can see that the margin is still there even though it was set to 0 for left and right.

[image]

First I checked if any other class or id is doing this, but it is not.

What is going on? I even tried it with `!important` but it made no difference.

```css
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}

.header {
    background: black;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
}

.main {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-top: 120px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.containerFooter {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.innerContainer {
    padding-left: 6%;
}

.carObject {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #ffdbdb;
    width: 380px;
    height: 512px;
}

.imagesWrap {
    margin-top: 50px;
    min-height: 250px;
    min-width: 352px;
}

.image {
    /*width: 444px;*/
    height: 280px;
    margin:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

.car_image {
    display: inline;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.carObjectEdit {
    border: 2px solid #ffdbdb;
    min-width: 300px;
    width: 380px;
}

.carTitleContainer {
    font-family: fantasy;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    height: 24px;
    /*min-height:40px;*/
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right:4px;
    margin-top:4px;

}
    .close:hover {
        color: red;
    }
.edit {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right:4px;
    margin-top:4px;
}
    .edit:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
        color: red;
    }

.carProperties {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-family: arial;
}

.detailsDescription {
    min-height: 100px;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px #d8d8d8 solid;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

p.detailsDescription {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

table.details tr td {

    min-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

table.details tr td:nth-child(odd) {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: right;
}

/* --------------Full Responsive Design--------------------*/
.FilterContainer{
    overflow-x:auto;
    margin-top: 150px;
    width: 740px;
    border: 1px outset #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 11px 43px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 11px 43px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow: 10px 11px 43px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    padding: 10px;
}
.createContainer {
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

@media (max-width:1600px) and (min-width:1200px) {
    .createContainer {
        width: 800px;
    }

}
@media (max-width:1200px) and (min-width:769x) {
    .createContainer {
        width: 400px;
    }

}
@media (max-width:769x) and (min-width:360px) {
    .createContainer {
        width: 270px;
    }

}
@media (max-width:360px) {
    .createContainer {
        width: 225px;
    }
}
/*-Login-----------------*/
.navbar-form {
    margin-right: 80px;
    transform: scale(0.85);
    padding-top: 4px;
}

@media (max-width:1850px) and (min-width:1600px) {
        
    .navbar-form {
        width: auto;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 320px;
        margin-left: 0;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        
    }
}

@media (max-width:1600px) and (min-width:1500px) {
    .navbar-form {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 600px;
        margin-left: 0;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width:1500px) and (min-width:1400px) {
    .navbar-form {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 650px;
        margin-left: 0;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width:1400px) and (min-width:1300px) {
    .navbar-form {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 675px;
        margin-left: 0;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width:1300px) and (min-width:1200px) {
    .navbar-form {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 750px;
        margin-left: 0;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width:1200px) and (min-width:1100px) {
    .navbar-form {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 800px;
        margin-left: 0;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width:1100px) and (min-width:600px) {
    .navbar-form {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 1000px;
        transform:scale(0.75);
        margin-left: 0;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width:1000px) and (min-width:800px) {
    .navbar-form {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 1080px;
        transform:scale(0.75);
        margin-left: 0;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width:800px) and (min-width:600px) {
    .navbar-form {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 1100px;
        transform:scale(0.75);
        margin-left: 0;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    .FooterButton {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:600px) and (min-width:300px) {
    .navbar-form {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 1100px;
        transform:scale(0.75);
        margin-left: 0;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    .FooterButton {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:300px) {
    .navbar-form {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 1100px;
        transform:scale(0.75);
        margin-left: 0;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    .FooterButton {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
/* ENDE --------------Full Responsive Design--------------------*/
/* ------------------ diverses ----------------------*/

.error {
    padding:10px;
    color: red;
}

.errorLog {
    color: red;
}

a.animatedLink {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.animatedLink:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.animatedLink:hover::after, a.animatedLink:focus::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

a.animatedLink::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
  transform: translateY(8px);
}

/* ------------------ constantin --------------------*/

.ListContainer{
    margin-top: 120px;
    width: 850px;
    border: 1px outset #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 11px 43px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 11px 43px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow: 10px 11px 43px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    padding: 10px;
}

.DetailContainer{
    margin-top: 120px;
    width: 1200px;
    border: 1px outset #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 11px 43px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 11px 43px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow: 10px 11px 43px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    padding: 10px;
}

.KontaktContainer{
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 850px;
    height: 550px;
    border: 1px outset #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 11px 43px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 11px 43px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow: 10px 11px 43px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    padding: 10px;
}

.InseratContainer{
    margin-top: 120px;
    width: 740px;
    border: 1px outset #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 11px 43px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 11px 43px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow: 10px 11px 43px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    padding: 10px;
}

.form-group{
    padding: 7px;
}

label{
    width: 150px;
}

select{
    width: 220px !important;
}

input{
    width: 220px !important;
}

.SubmitButton{
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align:center;
}

button{
    font-size: 20px !important;
}

h3{
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

.Login{
    position: absolute;
    right: 7px;
}


.navbar-inverse{
    height: 60px;
}

.navbar-brand{
    position: absolute;
    left: 13px;
    top: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
}
.navbar-brand:hover{
    color: red;
}

.Menu{
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
    top: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

 /* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
    color: white;
    margin-top: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}


/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    border: 1px;
}

/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 20px;
}



.MenuHide{
    transform: scale(0.5);
    padding-left:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top: -3px;
    right:15px;
    margin: 15px;
    z-index: 500;
}
    .MenuHide:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
    }

.btn{
    text-align: left;
}

.modal-dialog-reg{
    width: 268px !important;
}

.modal-dialog-anm{
    width: 505px !important;
}

.modal-footer{
    text-align: center;
}



.ListImg{
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.ListView{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.CarouselContainer{
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}

.DetailImg{
    width: 600px;
    height: 380px;
}

.backendContainer {
    border:1px solid black;
}
.backendContainer img {
    height: 175px;
    border: none;
}

.deleteAreYouSure {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 4px;
}
.edit {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 4px;
}

.FooterButton{
    color: #d4d4d4;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.FooterButton:hover{
    color: white;
}

.FooterTitle {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="description" content="Simple CMS"/>
<meta name="author" content="Sheikh Heera"/>

<title>LaraPress</title>

<body>
    <div class="header">
       <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href='http://localhost/-auto-shop/shop/public'>This is the header</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 MenuHide" onClick="openNav();" id="MenuHide">
                <img class="MenuHideIcon" src="http://localhost/-auto-shop/shop/public/img/menu.png">
            </div>
        </div>
</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="container m-0">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                  <h2>Datenschutz</h2>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

                      Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 

                      Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. 

                      Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

                      Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis. 

                      At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat. 

                      Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus. 

                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

                      Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 

                      Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. 
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <!-- SideNav -->
                <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                    <button class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">
                        <i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                        <a href="http://localhost/-auto-shop/shop/public/user/showAccount"><i class="fa fa-id-card"></i>&nbsp;Hans</a>

                    <a href='http://localhost/-auto-shop/shop/public/car/showAll'><i class="fa fa-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Inserate</a>

                            <a href='http://localhost/-auto-shop/shop/public/car/create'><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Verkaufen</a>
                        <a href='http://localhost/-auto-shop/shop/public/logout'><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> Abmelden</a>
                    </div>
                <!-- SideNav ENDE --> 
                </div>
              
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <h3 class="FooterTitle">&copy; 2017 </h3>

<div class="FooterButtonWrap">
    <a class="FooterButton animatedLink" href='http://localhost/-auto-shop/shop/public/impressum'>Impressum</a>
    <a class="FooterButton animatedLink" href='http://localhost/-auto-shop/shop/public/datenschutz'>Datenschutz</a>
    <a class="FooterButton animatedLink" href='http://localhost/-auto-shop/shop/public/haftungsausschluss'>Haftungsausschluss</a>
    <a class="FooterButton animatedLink" href='http://localhost/-auto-shop/shop/public/agb'>AGB</a>
    <a class="FooterButton animatedLink" href='http://localhost/-auto-shop/shop/public/kontakt'>Kontakt</a>
</div>    </div>

</body>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bqxgeo2/11/)

UPDATE:

It is related with the weird @media settings.
I noticed that it works if I uncheck each one of them:

[image]

Why is Bootstrap 4 designed like this and how can I disable this "feature"?

EDIT: I "downgraded" to 3.3.7 again, no headache anymore...

Comment: i suppoes it's a block element that has a width defined

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"I **downgraded** to 3.3.7 again, no headache anymore"*? You simply switched from 3.x to 4.x and expected it to work? If so, please consider reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091275/upgrading-bootstrap-from-3-3-4-to-4-0/49091398#49091398).

Comment: It's working as expected. `container` has a defined px width (except for mobile where it's 100% width). When you remove the auto margins it becomes left aligned. Maybe you want `container-fluid`?

Comment: You're using `.m-0`, which applies `margin:0!important` on `.container`, which uses left and right margin values of `auto` to be centered. In current form it's not clear what you want to achieve. Could you clarify your question? If you want your `.container` to have 100% width, use `.container-fluid`

Comment: ahh, i thought that `.m-0` does `margin: 0px` ... I wanted to achieve `margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;`. `container-fluid` did exactly what I wanted!! :) thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `.m-0`, which applies `margin:0!important;` on `.container`, which uses left and right margin values of `auto`, combined with hard-coded `width`s, **to be centered**.

If you want your `.container` to fill the entire screen, use `.container-fluid`.

---

Ample note regarding use of `.m-0` and the likes:

Unfortunately, Bootstrap chose a weird (if you ask me) way to develop a new system of imposing `margin`s and `padding`s in v4. It's weird (and wrong, IMHO) because it is way too powerful in terms of specificity.
In short, it implies the use of `!important` for classes of type `m-*` and `p-*`. It also creates numerous problems when you need different margin/padding values applied responsively.
As far as I'm concerned, it's a mistake and I personally chose not to use this system at all, in any of my projects.

If you choose to use them, get used to using `!important` and at least one `.className` to apply your desired values over Bootstrap's selectors.

The obvious alternative is to not use `.m-*` and `.p-*` classes at all and apply `margin`s and `padding`s as in previous versions of Bootstrap, without the need to use `!important`.

---

<strike>**Note:** Posting images of code is quite wrong (on SO), for several reasons:</strike>

- it denies indexing, so people with a similar error won't be able to find it by searching the error (when you're posting an error)
- most times, it's a lot easier and faster to understand a code if you see the result and inspect it, which is not possible when you post an image of code

Do consider replacing the images with the actual code or adding a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, featuring your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap4 uses flexbox. Try to set `display: inline-flex` - you can add the class: `.d-inline-flex`