# Can't allign input fields with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I don't know how to resize the left box to be at the width of its placeholder.

Roughly size wise I want it to look something like this:

[image: image ex]

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <label for="phonNum"> Please enter phone Number</label>
  <div class="row text-left">
    <div class="form-group form-inline" show-errors>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength=3 name="phoneInt" placeholder="000" ng-model="client.phoneIn">
      </div>
      <div class="col"></div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength=10 name="phone" placeholder="670125" ng-model="client.phone">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it:

```
   <div class="container">
        <label for="phonNum"> Please enter phone Number</label>
        <div class="row text-left">
            <div class="form-group form-inline" show-errors>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength=3 name="phoneInt" size="3" placeholder="000"
                        ng-model="client.phoneIn">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength=10 name="phone" placeholder="1234567891"
                        ng-model="client.phone">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

check https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/ba5jhosn/1/

Comment: This is NOT it. The question is marked bootstrap 4 and you have used bootstrap 3 in your fiddle. There are no -xs tags in bootstrap 4. They have been replaced. Please check my answer below.

Comment: No it isn't. Your col-xs-6 class does nothing. Remove it in your fiddle and you will see there is no change. The -xs-* classes have been replaced with col-*

Comment: Also please provide some explanation about what the problem was and what you fixed in your answer.

Comment: You have added size="3" on the first input. That's not using bootstrap's grid

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML tags are a little bit wrong. The 2nd col div closes right away instead of going around the 2nd input.

I have changed your fiddle a little bit with proper tag alignment and I've used col-3 on the first input and just col for the 2nd to take up the remaining grid space. Going col-2 on the first will make it even smaller. Remember there are a total of 12 columns in bootstrap's grid!

https://jsfiddle.net/mtx2nu0y/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<label for="phonNum"> Please enter phone Number</label>
  <div class="row text-left" >
    <div class="form-group form-inline"  show-errors>
      <div class="col-3">
        <input type="text" id="phoneInt" class="form-control" maxlength=3  name="phoneInt" placeholder="000" ng-model="client.phoneIn">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="phone" class="form-control" maxlength=10  name="phone" placeholder="1234567891" ng-model="client.phone">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

#phoneInt, #phone {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a link to bootstap's grid documentation
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Thank you.That was my oversight. When removed as seen in the fiddle the fields are connected. I want them to be separated. If you add <div class="col-xs-3"> on the first div I will get them as I want but then the left div needs to be resized.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you click on my fiddle, the fields ARE separated. There is space between them. What are you trying to achieve with -xs ? The XS tags have been dropped in bootstrap 4. Please have a read at the documentation link I provided. Also please have a look at this explaining the change: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794746/col-xs-not-working-in-bootstrap-4

Comment: This is incorrect totally sizes of smaller box is changing  on window resize

Comment: He said he wants it for a small screen (xs), not a large one. I've updated my fiddle to work on all screensizes, with bootstrap, even if he was just trying to do it for small screens.