# How to change the offset size in bootstrap 4 grids?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 4 in my Angular 8 application. In my main page I have two components of size `md-5` and `md-6` and I want to separate them using `offset-md-1`. But the offset size is big and I don't want to have that much space between my components. How do I reduce the size of the `offset`? Will `offset-md-0.5` work? Can you suggest any better way other than using bootstrap `offset`?
This is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container1 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5">
            <app-projectstatus></app-projectstatus>
        </div>
        <div class="container2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 offset-md-1">
            <app-upcomingreleases></app-upcomingreleases>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap has 12 columns by standard, if one column offset is too big, you might want to change the amount of columns to 24. AFAIK with Bootstrap LESS/SASS you can simply change the parameter in the mixin call and et`voila.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ml-auto` instead of `offset-md-1` it works perfect for you.

try this code:

```
<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container1 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5">
            <app-projectstatus></app-projectstatus>
        </div>
        <div class="container2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 ml-auto">
            <app-upcomingreleases></app-upcomingreleases>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will works perfect for you.

**Note:** I Can't understand that how `offset-md-1` size is big? the default css property for this class is fixed `margin-left: 8.333333%;` in bootstrap. you can use this class also but condition is that you do not have to make any kind of changes in `col-**-*` width.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

There is no `*-xs-*` classes in bootstrap-4. Use `col-12` instead.
[`col-xs-*` not working in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794746/col-xs-not-working-in-bootstrap-4)

---

Ther are three ways to add space between columns.

1. `margin-x` on `.col-*`
2. `padding-x` on `.col-*`
3. `justify-content-between` on `.row`

Margin is quite tricky since it affects the sum of width of total columns. The  width + margin-x of the two columns should not exceed the width of `.row`. Otherwise, the columns breaks.

The total width of the two columns on md-screen is `91.667%`. So you have `8.333%` free sapce. You can control where to use this `8.333%`.

`offset-md-1`,`mr-auto`, `ml-auto` and `justify-content-between` yeilds the same result: `8.333%` space betwen the two columns.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="container1 col-12 col-md-6  bg-primary">
        
    </div>
    <div class="container2 col-12 col-md-5 offset-md-1 bg-danger ">
        offset-md-1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="container1 col-12 col-md-6 mr-auto bg-primary">
        mr-auto
    </div>
    <div class="container2 col-12 col-md-5 bg-danger ">
        
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="container1 col-12 col-md-6 bg-primary">
        
    </div>
    <div class="container2 col-12 col-md-5 bg-danger ">
        ml-auto
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="container1 col-12 col-md-6 bg-primary">
        justify-content-between
    </div>
    <div class="container2 col-12 col-md-5 bg-danger ">
    justify-content-between
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to have `8.333% / 2` space betwen them. You can not do it in bootstrap-4. So you need  to use `css`.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .ml-md-0_5 {
    margin-left: calc((100% / 12) / 2)
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid padding">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container1 col-12 col-md-6 bg-primary">
      
    </div>
    <div class="container2 col-12 col-md-5 bg-danger ml-md-0_5">
      ml-md-0_5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, the total width + margin of both of the columns is `95.833%`. By default, the elements  are left aligned. Therefore,   `4.166%` free sapce on the right side of the last column. You can use it on x-side of any of  the columns if you wish so.

As said before, you can use `padding-x` also which i prefer because it does not affect the total width of the columns.