# How to format specific padding/margin rules on different screen sizes?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

```
<div className="col-lg-6 text-lg-left mt-lg-0 col-md-12 mt-md-3 text-md-center" />
```

where on large screen devices, I want the div to be text aligned to the left, have no margin-top

On medium screen devices, I want the col to be full width, have margin top of 3rem and be centered. This works great and everything however, on small screen sizes, I also want the rules I have on medium screen sizes to persist as well as on xs screen sizes. However, it doesn't.

So I tried this:

```
<div className="col-lg-6 text-lg-left mt-lg-0 col-md-12 mt-md-3 text-md-center col-sm-12 mt-sm-3 text-sm-center" />
```

thinking it would work but it doesn't. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I looked at the documentation and their is a sm and xs classes in the documentation I can use but it's not working on those smaller screen devices.

So my question is how can I persist the rules I have on medium screen devices to small and xs classes? I don't want to write custom medium queries I want to try and stick solely to the bootstrap framework.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, always define the rules for smaller breakpoints as they are carried over to the larger breakpoints automatically.

Thus a rule defined for Extra Small (`xs`) screen is applied all the way upto the Large (`lg`) screens until it's specified explicitly. So, if you have a specific setting for `xs` and `sm` define for `xs`, and if you have same setting for `md` and `lg` define it for `md`.

Also, in Bootstrap 4, the `xs` attribute has been dropped. Thus `col-xs-3` in Bootstrap 3 becomes `col-3` in Bootstrap 4.

Refer the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794746/col-xs-not-working-in-bootstrap-4) for more info.

As for your solution, update the `div` as below

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 text-lg-left mt-lg-0 col-12 mt-3 text-center">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

Below is a snippet for the same

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 text-lg-left mt-lg-0 col-12 mt-3 text-center">
            Hello World!
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```