# how to align div side by side using bootstrap for mobile?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I know using below bootstrap  I can easy align **div side by** side but it's only work for desktop not for mobile.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:pink;">
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: [click here to see](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPCM837LOY49)

**Desktop output:**

[image: hre]

**Mobile output**

[image: here]

As you can see the columns stack horizontally when it hit  `765 x 645 @media_property`
So, how would it be possible to display the columns in mobile as same it seems in desktop mode side by side?

Comment: Since you're using Bootstrap 3, define your columns as col-xs-6.

Comment: @RichDeBourke, Bootstrap 4 is tagged.

Comment: @isherwood yes!

Comment: @isherwood - the question *is* tagged bootstrap-4, but the *demo* on W3Schools is running Bootstrap 3.4.1.

Comment: sory it was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

define your colums as col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 to have them side by side in every device

Comment: didn't get your point can you elaborate?

Comment: Those `xs` classes don't exist in Bootstrap 4. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794746/col-xs-not-working-in-bootstrap-4.

Comment: Those classes work in Boostrap 4 except of the col-xs-6. Just write  class = "col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6" to both your columns :)

Comment: I appreciate, thanks kristel to answer my question and thankyou all.. specially isherwood:)

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to this @tao from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41795300/10798348).

`col-xs-*` have been dropped in `Bootstrap 4` in favor of `col-*`.

Replace `col-xs-12` with `col-12` and it will work as expected.

Also note `col-xs-offset-{n}` were replaced by `offset-{n}` in v4.

**So after bit of changes...**
`col-sm-6` to `col-6`

```
 <div class="container">
          <h1>Hello World!</h1>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
              <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6" style="background-color:pink;">
              <p>Sed ut perspiciatis...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Demo v4: [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPCNO70SAOQX)